# How to upgrade SAP HANA XS Node.js Engine

Tags: node.js, hana, hana-xs

Version of `node.js` engine `v8.x` in `SAP HANA XS`. But when I make this value 10.x I get the error.
The `package.json` in the `Node.js` application looks like this:

```
    {
      "name": "server",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      ...,
      "dependencies": {
        "@sap/hana-client": "^2.4.144",
        "express": "^4.15.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "8.x"
      }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js on HANA XSA can only be updated by updating HANA XSA itself. To get Node 10 support you need to update to the HANA XSA Runtime delivered with HANA 2.0 SPS04. For details please check the [release notes](https://help.sap.com/viewer/42668af650f84f9384a3337bcd373692/2.0.04/en-US/3f73830a0f4b42ce9b359535455d654e.html) or SAP Note [2741459](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2741459).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your XSA please run command `xs runtimes | grep node` that way you will see what "Node's" you already got. For example:

```
node10.15             3.0       57   true       true     Node.js 10.15.3 for Linux x86-64               17
node6.14              4.3       4    true       true     Node.js 6.14.4.3 for Linux x86-64              1
node6.15              1.0       38   true       true     Node.js 6.15.1 for Linux x86-64                7
node8.11              4.4       3    true       true     Node.js 8.11.4.4 for Linux x86-64              1
node8.14              0.0       39   true       true     Node.js 8.14.0 for Linux x86-64                1
node8.15              0.1       48   true       true     Node.js 8.15.0.1 for Linux x86-64              1
node8.15              1.3       56   true       true     Node.js 8.15.1.3 for Linux x86-64              110
```